# How to apply equivalence test of whether data come from a specified distribution?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, equivalence

I have evenly-spaced locations from $1, 2, \dotsc, 1000$. At each location I have data from my $N$ samples coming from two groups, and I apply a (one-sided) test to obtain a p-value. I want to know if there is some pattern to the locations of low p-values (e.g. p < 5%), although I don't have any specific pattern I'd like to test against. The usual (non-equivalence) test of these data would use the null hypothesis that the locations are uniformly distributed on [1, 1000] and apply a test such as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. In my case, this yields a high p-value.

However, I'd like an equivalence test that can accept if the locations of the significant p-values is uniform. There are some related posts on this, with the closest being [Is there a simple equivalence test version of the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/is-there-a-simple-equivalence-test-version-of-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test). The answers in this post construct equivalence bounds on the KS statistic, but my understanding is that equivalence bounds are for effect sizes, but the KS statistic is not an effect size, because it depends on the number of significant locations. Further, the number of significant locations should also depend on my sample size, since more samples means more power means more significant locations, although I'm not certain if this is relevant. (Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on that post.)