# hypothesis test: difference greater than threshold

Tags: hypothesis-testing, equivalence

Hypothesis tests are commonly framed as

$H_0:  p_0 = p_1$     vs.     $H_1:  p_0 \not= p_1$.

But I am interested in the case:

$H_0:  |p_0 - p_1| < c $     vs.     $H_1:  |p_0 - p_1| \ge c $

for some constant $c$.

Could I apply a likelihood ratio test? - the degrees of freedom would be the same in both cases, I suppose?

Would I have to go Bayesian and apply an (arbitrary) prior?

Comment: What are $p_0$ and $p_1$? Probabilities, statistics, models?

Comment: parametric parameters.  "Hypothesis tests are **commonly** framed as..." and I do believe it is typically presented as a test of parametric parameter(s).

Comment: Look into tests of equivalence:  See for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52897/equivalence-tests-for-non-normal-data  and search this site for [tag:equivalence]  and  [tag:tost]